# @uniswap/smart-order-router throws TypeError: n.BigInt is not a function in production nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, uniswap

I am implementing @uniswap to a nuxt 3 project I am working on. Everything is working fine locally and this is my code:

```
import JSBI from 'jsbi'; //v3.2.5
import { CurrencyAmount, Percent, ChainId as SupportedChainId, Token, TradeType } from '@uniswap/sdk-core'; //v4.0.1
import { AlphaRouter, ChainId, SwapType, SwapOptionsSwapRouter02  } from '@uniswap/smart-order-router'; //v3.13.2-hotfix2 also tried, v2.10.2, v3.6.1
```

```
const fromReadableAmount = (amount: number, decimals: number) => {
    const extraDigits = Math.pow(10, countDecimals(amount))
    const adjustedAmount = amount * extraDigits
    return JSBI.divide(
        JSBI.multiply(
            JSBI.BigInt(adjustedAmount),
            JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(10), JSBI.BigInt(decimals))
        ),
        JSBI.BigInt(extraDigits)
    )
};
```

I narrowed the origin of the error to this piece of code, particularly the Percent object created in the `slippageTolerance` property in the `options` object.

```
const options: SwapOptionsSwapRouter02 = {
    recipient: authStore.getWallet as string,
    slippageTolerance: new Percent(50, 10_000),
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 1800),
    type: SwapType.SWAP_ROUTER_02
}
    
const currentConfig = {
    'tokenIn': swap.from.token === 'tusdt' ? supportedTokens.tusdt : supportedTokens.wpc,
    'amountIn': fromReadableAmount(
                swap.from.amount,
                swap.from.token === 'tusdt' ? supportedTokens.tusdt.decimals : supportedTokens.wpc.decimals
     ).toString(),
    'tokenOut': swap.to.token === 'tusdt' ? supportedTokens.tusdt : supportedTokens.wpc,
}
    
let router = new AlphaRouter({
            chainId: ChainId.POLYGON_MUMBAI,
            provider: provider.value
});
        
const route = await router.route(
     CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(
        currentConfig.tokenIn,
        currentConfig.amountIn
     ),
     currentConfig.tokenOut,
     TradeType.EXACT_INPUT,
     options
);
```

So, the `options` object is passed to the `route` method. I get no error locally, but in production I get `TypeError: n.BigInt is not a function`, a fatal error, the page does not get rendered at all. Which I don't get because this code is inside a function that is only called when a user clicks on a button. That is not the problem though,why does this work locally but not in production? Is this a nuxt issue or a @uniswap issue

[error in the browser: production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E0vS.png)

This is a snippet of the minified code in production when I click on the error:

```
const xE = Object.freeze(Object.defineProperty({
    __proto__: null,
    FACTORY_ADDRESS: t5,
    INIT_CODE_HASH: n5,
    InsufficientInputAmountError: Ia,
    InsufficientReservesError: _a,
    MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY: r5,
    Pair: Ni,
    Route: ss,
    Router: IE,
    Trade: _E,
    computePairAddress: f5,
    inputOutputComparator: u5,
    tradeComparator: wu
}, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    value: "Module"
}))
  , CE = yi(xE)
  , SE = yi(l3);
(function(r) {
    function e(R) {
        return R && typeof R == "object" && "default"in R ? R.default : R
    }
    Object.defineProperty(r, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    });
    var t, n = e(l4), s = d4, a = e(p4), f = w4, u = E4, l = O4, d = V4, h = eE, m = uE, y = CE, g = SE, T = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", I = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002", S = n.BigInt(0), N = n.BigInt(1);
    function G(R) {
        return Object.keys(R).some(function(B) {
            return B === "recipient"
        })
    }
    (t = r.ApprovalTypes || (r.ApprovalTypes = {}))[t.NOT_REQUIRED = 0] = "NOT_REQUIRED",
    t[t.MAX = 1] = "MAX",
    t[t.MAX_MINUS_ONE = 2] = "MAX_MINUS_ONE",
    t[t.ZERO_THEN_MAX = 3] = "ZERO_THEN_MAX",
    t[t.ZERO_THEN_MAX_MINUS_ONE = 4] = "ZERO_THEN_MAX_MINUS_ONE";
```

This code should be from the Percent class, or the class it extends here: [Percent](https://github.com/Uniswap/sdk-core/blob/main/src/entities/fractions/percent.ts)

We have `node v18.16.0` in production and I was using `node v16.14.2` locally. I could not replicate the issue locally even after switching my node version to `node v18.16.0`.
I also attempted to move this code to the server-side, which only created more problems.

Comment: Need to polyfil JSBI theres a bug in uniswap answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769749/vite-app-works-in-dev-but-not-after-build-and-preview-bigint-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I never got this to work but I got a work around and got it to work in both development and in production. It was less favourable but it worked. I was using nuxt v3.2.0 by the way. Instead of using the @uniswap/smart-order-router, I used the [SwapRouter](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/trading) to make the trades. Uniswap however recommends the [@uniswap/smart-order-router](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/routing) over this.